# Flipper will not pause at any breakpoints - react-native - react-native-reanimated

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated-v2, flipper

I have recently moved to debugging with Flipper after installing react-native-reanimated, however it doesn't pause on breakpoints.

I am using react-native 0.65.0 and react-native-reanimated 2.3.0-alpha.3.

The log in the screenshot is in the console however the debugger does not pause.

[image]

Has anyone else had this problem and found a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up downgrading react-native-reanimated to version 1.13.2 and reverting back to using React Native Debugger.